# how to delete post using socket.io mysql nodejs express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm learning to do simple messaging app which allows user to add the status and in real time update it to feeds of everyone.

I am using socket.io, mysql, nodejs and express.
User can send message in real time.
In browser startup, it load all data in database.

I'd like to ask how could I delete message based in ID ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how you currently pull the post cant give as detailed of a response, but lets assume you emit that from your socket as well..

The websockets are a persistent connection to the users, because of that both client and server can emit or receive commands. With that knowledge we can now just 'emit' from the 'client' to the 'server' a command that the post has been 'deleted' when the 'client' emits to the 'server' the socket server can then delete the post from the DB, after the deletion has been completed it will then 'emit' to the 'client' who has a listener for 'postDelete' (or whatever you want to call it) that may contain the updated post list OR it could have another call that runs an update post function etc.

** Edit **

To add a bit more to this.

It's important to remember that socket.io is really just a message broker of sorts. It can GET and EMIT messages, you tell it how and what to do for each.
So to the question as to how you would go about 'deleting' the message is really no different then how you would go about it normally

1. (client) user clicks delete, 'emits' to server
2. Server is 'listening' for the 'emit' on X command to delete
3. Server gets command, inside of '.on' for delete is your 'delete' code (will probably be SQL to remove from DB)
4. After command is run and successful you will then 'emit' from server with the new payload of 'posts'
5. Client has a ".on" to listen for new or updated 'posts' server 'emits' to this
6. Client get new 'emits' from server with the updated JSON and updates the screen.

Comment: The best way of thinking about it, is to not think in terms of how you do it via socket.io VS how you would do it without.. Sounds dumb but all socket.io is, is the message broker. A set of listeners on both ends (clicen and server). Inside each 'listener' is your code. So how you 'delete' a post from your DB would just be a regular 'DELETE FROM DB where X = ID' then return the response to the client ( could be JSON or another set of instructions to do something )